# How to import flutter project from windows to linux?

Tags: data-structures, flutter

I developed an application on windows and these days i switched back to Linux and i installed everything and copied the whole project but it didn't work, is there any to transfer the same app without recreating a new one

Comment: what didn't work?

Comment: it said something referes to C//users//mypc.... when i moved the need files to another new created project in linux it worked but it became a new app now can install it as an update to the old one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your new OS has proper setup for flutter and running `flutter doctor` in terminal doesn't show any issue.

1. Copy your project to the new OS.
2. Open terminal in your project directory.
3. `flutter clean` in terminal.
4. and then `flutter packages get`
5. `flutter run`

This should work for you.